# Why does my Android Unit Test runs twice?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Here is the complete test class for my Kotlin unit tests:

```
package xyz.hitit.userapplication.unittests.fragmentUnitTests
import androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario
import androidx.fragment.app.testing.launchFragmentInContainer
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import xyz.hitit.userapplication.ui.registrationLogin.VerificationCodeFragment

class VerificationCodeFragmentUnitTests {
    var scenario: FragmentScenario<VerificationCodeFragment>? = null

    @Before
    fun setup() {
         scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<VerificationCodeFragment>()
    }

    @Test
    fun testHandleVerificationCodeResult2() {
        scenario?.onFragment { sut ->
            sut.didRun = false
            var menu = "NotAnEmailSearch"
            sut.handleVerificationCodeResult(menu = menu, userInputVerCode = "list2")
            assert(sut.didRun == true)
        }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        scenario = null
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this test class `testHandleVerificationCodeResult2()`  runs twice and the last one fails. Which process should I take to find the solution??

Comment: Why is it called `testHandleVerificationCodeResult2`? Is there a `testHandleVerificationCodeResult` in the class as well? If so, you need to post the whole class.

Comment: Could you check is there multiple testing framework imported as dependency?

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu could you be more specific? where can i check that in my build.gradle(app)?

Comment: Yes you should check if there are multiple test frameworks both in implementation and testImplementation

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu such as 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.4'
   implementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
??

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a dummy fragment? Maybe VerificationCodeFragment contains complex logic that makes this happen, for some reason.

Comment: Can you execute test code after removing junit 4.12?

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu Nope..